# Selenium / Python / IG Requests

Tags: python

I am trying to make an Instagram bot that can perform various functions - InstaPy kept timing out on me so I decided to use selenium BUT the issue is: I can't seem to get the past the first hurdle of actually logging into IG.

I am not getting any errors on the console but it won't let me past the past additional cookies acceptance page. I have played with the xpath and done a few tweeks but still nothing - any ideas on a fix here ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time, urllib.request
import requests

PATH = r"/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject13/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')

#login
time.sleep(5)

notnow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2], 'Allow Essential and Optional Cookies')]").click()

username=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")   #arialabelondevtools = #Phone number, username or email address
password=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys("testacct1")
password.send_keys("testpassword123")

login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: make sure you are not sharing actual login and password here...

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common mistake that people do is write absolute xpath or probably you are copying xpath from browser it self so instead use smarter xpath use id, class and other attributes to write xpath..

I recently did login to Instagram and here is the simple go

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="username"]').send_keys('your_login')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys('your_password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').submit()
```

once you past login page you can

```
driver.get('https://instagram.com/')
```

it will reload to your home page...